# Getting error while generation of model in JRuby

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, jruby, jrubyonrails

Hi I am getting error while I am generating the model. Following the error stack i am facing.

```
   rails generate model id:string name:string userid:string groupid:string bookmarktype:string typeid:string additionaldata:string
    include_class is deprecated. Use java_import.
    include_class is deprecated. Use java_import.
    Resolved collector.newrelic.com to 204.93.223.153
          invoke  active_record
    NameError: wrong constant name Id:string
                const_defined? at org/jruby/RubyModule.java:2608
              class_collisions at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:267
                          each at org/jruby/RubyArray.java:1612
              class_collisions at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/base.rb:249
         check_class_collision at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/railties-3.2.3/lib/rails/generators/named_base.rb:183
                      __send__ at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1667
                          send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2060
                           run at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/task.rb:21
                   invoke_task at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:118
                    invoke_all at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124
                          each at org/jruby/RubyHash.java:1192
                           map at org/jruby/RubyEnumerable.java:715
                    invoke_all at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:124
                      dispatch at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:226
                      __send__ at org/jruby/RubyBasicObject.java:1694
                          send at org/jruby/RubyKernel.java:2072
                        invoke at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/invocation.rb:109
      _invoke_for_class_method at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/group.rb:269
                  with_padding at /home/anand/.rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.0.preview2/gems/thor-0.14.6/lib/thor/shell.rb:74
```

Following is the output of rvm list

```
rvm list

rvm rubies

=* jruby-1.7.0.preview2 [ i386 ]
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]

# => - current
# =* - current && default
#  * - default
```

I am using Ubuntu 12.04. How to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to provide the model name while generating with the fields. For example,

```
rails generate model UserDetails id:string name:string userid:string groupid:string bookmarktype:string typeid:string additionaldata:string
```

'UserDetails' is the model name.

It's might be the problem. Not sure what you are asking clearly. Cheers!